# Access ng-model created via an isolate scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I have a simple directive using isolate scope which passes data to a scoped method from within the template:

```
app.directive("phone", function () {
    return {
      scope: {
        dial: "&"
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value">' +
        '<br>' +
        '<div class="button" ng-click="dial({message:value})">' +
        'Call home!</div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log($scope);
      }
    };
  });
```

Works fine. But I'd like to clear the input field after the alert has been completed. I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can access `ng-model="value"` on that input that is generated from within the directive. Any help?

Here's a [plunk for you](http://plnkr.co/edit/0mDrUrUD9GXupGp7t8uj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the template to this

```
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="value">' +
        '<br>' +
        '<div class="button" ng-click="dial({message:value}); value = \'\' ">' +
        'Call home!</div>',
```

note that `ng-click` is changed to `ng-click="dial({message:value}); value = \'\' "`

this will sets the `value` to empty string after calling the `dial()` function.

here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUAHh0YEzCTs1Y4aqTj8?p=preview)

or you can try something [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/oj1OpGgzV1QaHi7SHA8s?p=preview), but seems like first one is the better one.